# Are Windows 8.1 Pro Student and Windows 8.1 Pro same?, or there is difference or reduced features before of that huge price difference they have?

Tags: windows-7

Are Windows 8.1 Pro Student and Windows 8.1 Pro same?, or is there a difference or reduced features because of that huge price difference they have?

Comment: I believe they are the same but, because students aren't expected to have loads of money, they have discounted the price. After your studies, in the eyes of the law, you're supposed to purchase your own retail copy.

Comment: Besides price, there are no difference. Microsoft Terms and Conditions only specifies that to purchase Student Edition, you need to be a full time or part time student and must be able to provide verification when requested [MS T&C AU version](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msaus/en_AU/html/pbPage.StudentStoreTermsandConditions). If you are a student, check [this page](http://onthehub.com/download/free-software/windows-8-pro-for-students/) - Your school/uni may already have free windows for you

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly the same version, includes all features that the pro does because it is the pro version, Microsoft always has great deals and promotions for students, a lot of universities will also have free downloads of Windows 8 and Microsoft Office as they normally have deals with Microsoft, you should ask around and maybe you can get it for free.